# Solve multiple small linear systems parallelly

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

I want to solve 10 linear systems (Ax = b) in each iteration of an algorithm.

The A of each system is about 10 x 11 (over-determined).

Cpu has 8 cores.

If I ask each CPU solve one of the 10 linear systems, 6 cpu has to wait for solving the last 2 systems.

If I solve each system one by one with multi-threaded solvers, would the performance be quite bad? I worry about false-sharing because the matrices A are small.

Does Eigen have a multi-threaded solver for this situation?

Thanks again.

Comment: Should I pad b and A with zeros?

Comment: Is it the same A for each system?

Comment: Not the same A.

Comment: Padding `A` may make sense to give it a size which is a multiple of the SIMD-packet size on your architecture (e.g., a multiple of 8, if you use float and AVX) -- but that depends on the solver you are using (you need to benchmark if it makes sense, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to leverage multi-threading within such tiny problems (`10 x 11`) will only slow down things. If you want to do better than running the 10 solves in parallel, then try to find more parallel tasks within your pipeline.

Comment: A minor thing which could be parallelized with the given problem is to split the decomposition and the solving (first decompose in 8 threads, then the remainder in 2 threads, solve the first 8 systems in the 6 threads which are not decomposing the last two systems) -- but doing that manually is probably premature micro-optimization.